# ExtJS 5 first steps, cannot see a simple grid with one store

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm

I'm trying to become familiar with Ext JS 5. I took a sencha generated app as
the start point and modified it to see a grid of one line.
But the page is simply blank.
Can anyone, please, show me what am I doing wrong?
I am not familiar with the MVVM pattern but I want to learn it.

Here's my set of files:

[image]

And here are the JS sources.

Applications.js

```
Ext.define('Admin.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'Admin'
});
```

Base.js (base class for models)

```
Ext.define('Admin.model.Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    schema: {
        namespace: 'Admin.model'
    }
});
```

Item.js (a simple model)

```
Ext.define('Admin.model.Item', {
    extend: 'Admin.model.Base',

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'title', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

ItemList.js (a store of items that I want to show in a grid)

```
Ext.define('Admin.store.ItemList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.itemlist',
    model: 'Admin.model.Item',
    data: [{id: 1, title: 'title1'}]
});
```

ItemListGrid.js (the panel with the grid)

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.main.ItemListGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    requires: [
        'Admin.store.ItemList'
    ],

    alias: 'widget.itemlistgrid',

    bind: {
        store: '{itemlist}',

        title: '<b>Some title</b>',

        columns: [{
            text: 'id',
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },{
            text: 'title',
            dataIndex: 'title'
        }]
    }
});
```

Main.js

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'Admin.view.main.MainController',
        'Admin.view.main.MainModel',
        'Admin.view.main.ItemListGrid'
    ],

    xtype: 'app-main',

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        //region: 'west',
        width: '100%',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'itemlistgrid'
        }]
    }]
});
```

MainController.js

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main'
});
```

MainModel.js

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.main.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

    alias: 'viewmodel.main',

    data: {
        name: 'Admin'
    },

    bind: {
        store: '{itemlist}'
    }
});
```

The `sencha app build` builds the app without errors. But I don't see the grid.
Before this I tried the default generated app and it showed in my browser OK.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the exact answer to my question https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299703-ExtJS-5-first-steps-cannot-see-a-simple-grid-with-one-store&p=1095022&viewfull=1#post1095022